# Add user to existing group in Yocto

Tags: yocto, openembedded

Let's say I create a user (named **www-data**) using the `useradd` class:

```
[...]
inherit useradd

USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"

USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "--system --no-create-home --home /var/www --groups www-data --user-group www-data"
[...]
```

Now I decide the user needs to run `journalctl ...` commands, so it should be a member of the `systemd-journal` group. Hence my recipe becomes:

```
[...]
inherit useradd

USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "--system --no-create-home --home /var/www --groups www-data,systemd-journal --user-group www-data"

[...]
```

The `systemd-journal` is present on the system (in both versions of the recipe), but `www-data` is not a part of it after I changed the recipe and I expected it to be a member of the group.

I also tried `GROUPADD_PARAMS_${PN} = "-r systemd-journal"`, but I got the same result, a user `www-data` that is not part of the `systemd-journal` group.

How am I supposed to accomplish this?

PS:
I fixed the issue by enabling a "first time boot" service in systemd that does the necessary setup once and then disables itself, but this seems hackish and I need to know what (if) I did something wrong above.

PPS: 
I also tried the `extrausers` class in order to `usermod -aG systemd-journal www-data`, but, again, no useful results.

Comment: You can add the user `www-data` in the sudoers allow only the journalctl, help? How did you do the routine to run at first boot?

Comment: @CleitonBueno, follow this tutorial: https://hub.mender.io/t/how-to-create-your-first-recipe-and-enable-auto-start-using-systemd/1195 But instead of starting `/usr/bin/hello`, start your own script.sh and run the commands you need there (usermod/chown/etc).

Comment: For me the following worked to add a user to sudo group: `inherit extrausers` and `EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -a -G sudo my-user"`. I'm sure the same should work for `systemd-journal` group instead of `sudo`.